# Убрать дубликаты при сортировке MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Есть MySQL запрос:

```
SELECT tasks.tid, tasks.ttype, tasks.ttitle, tasks.tcomments, tasks.turl 
 FROM `tasks` 
WHERE `tid` NOT IN (SELECT `tdtid` FROM `tasks_done` WHERE `tduid` = '15286') AND tasks.tfrom != '15286' 
ORDER BY tasks.tamount DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Как убрать дубликаты по tasks.turl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде всё так (tid я так понял primary key):

```
SELECT tasks.tid, tasks.ttype, tasks.ttitle, tasks.tcomments, tasks.turl from (
    SELECT tasks.turl, MIN(tasks.tid) as `tid` 
    FROM `tasks`
    WHERE `tid` NOT IN (SELECT `tdtid` FROM `tasks_done` WHERE `tduid` = '15286') AND tasks.tfrom != '15286'
    GROUP BY tasks.turl) a
JOIN 
    `tasks` 
ON a.tid = tasks.tid
ORDER BY tasks.tamount DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Штука в том, что в *select* должно быть только то что в *group by* и агрегатные функции.

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov, в плане производительности как этот запрос?

Answer (score 1):

С Новым годом, уважаемые участники!
А, по-моему, вот так:

```
select * from t 
where id in(
  select min(id) from t
  group by c1)
and c3 = '123'
order by c2;
```

или:

```
select * from t 
where id in(
  select min(id) from t
  group by c1 
  having c3 = '123')
order by c2;
```

Comment: Мне кажется второй вариант не подходит, т.к. в *having* может быть только то что в *group by*, потому что *having* выполняется после *group by*

Первый вариант медленнее, чем с join, потому что для каждой записи весь список пробегает id'ов.